# Flutter exception: Expected a value of type '(() => void)?' in Consumer

Tags: flutter, dart

My longin screen has following functions :

```
loginUIController() {
    return Consumer<ControllerLogin>(builder: (context, model, child) {
      // if user are already login
      if (model.userModel != null) {
        return Center(
          // show user details
          child: alreadyLoggedInScreen(model),
        );
      } else {
        // if user not login
        return notLoginScreen(model);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
notLoginScreen(ControllerLogin model) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Image.asset('assets/googleback.jpg'),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Provider.of<ControllerLogin>(context, listen: false).allowUserToLogin();
            },
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/google.png',
              width: 250,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The builder is :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: loginUIController(),
    );
  }
```

The notLoginScreen is displayed OK but every time I click Login button , the log shows a exception:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building Consumer<ControllerLogin>(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<ControllerLogin?>]):
Expected a value of type '(() => void)?', but got one of type '_Future<dynamic>'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Consumer<ControllerLogin>
  Consumer:file:///E:/CoderLife/Learning/flutter-learning/google_signin_authentication/lib/loginScreen.dart:17:12
```

The ControllerLogin is:

```
class ControllerLogin with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount;
  UserCredential? userCredential;

  UserModel? userModel;
  User? user;

  allowUserToLogin() async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      GoogleAuthProvider authProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();

      try {
        userCredential = await auth.signInWithPopup(authProvider);
        user = userCredential!.user;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

        try {
          userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
          user = userCredential!.user;
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            print(e);
          } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
            print(e);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    }

    if (user != null) {
      userModel = new UserModel(
          displayName: user!.displayName,
          email: user!.email,
          photoUrl: user!.photoURL);

      print(userModel!.toJson());

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  allowUserToLogOut() async {
    this.googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signOut();

    userModel = null;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The build function where Provider used is following:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ControllerLogin()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Google Login',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initApp,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print('error');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return LoginScreen();
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'v made onTap as a async function, but it didn't work.

It seems like I do sth wrong with Consumer stuff. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use consumer use Provider like this

```
 model =
        Provider.of<ControllerLogin>(context, listen: false).allowUserToLogin();
```